# How to insert values in a new row based on case statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

A new record or row should be added to a table when the case statement is satisfied. In azure sql, how can I insert a row. I want to apply this condition to a lot of records because there are millions of records.

Table Name:final_NW

following example show a single record in a table.

| MPRN | AB | ROLLING_AQ | FORMULA_YEAR_AQ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 2022-06-01 | 3400 | 4000 |

This is what I want have on millions of records based on different case conditions.

| MPRN | AB | ROLLING_AQ | FORMULA_YEAR_AQ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 2022-06-01 | 3400 | 4000 |
| 10001 | 2022-07-01 | 3400 | 4000 |

I have tried following query:

```
SELECT 
A.MPRN,
A.AB,
A.ROLLING_AQ,
A.FORMULA_YEAR_AQ,
CASE 
WHEN A.MPRN <> LEAD(A.MPRN) OVER (PARTITION BY 
A.MPRN ORDER BY A.AB) AND A.AB='2022-06-01' 
AND A.FORMULA_YEAR_AQ  <> 0 
THEN  
INSERT INTO A (MPRN,AB,ROLLING_AQ, FORMULA_YEAR_AQ  )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                VALUES ( A.MPRN,'2022-07-01',A.ROLLING_AQ,
A.FORMULA_YEAR_AQ)                                                                                        
ELSE
NULL
END as FYAQ_NEW

FROM final_NW A
```

and I am getting following error:
"Error in SQL statement: ParseException:
extraneous input ' ' expecting {'ELSE', 'END', 'WHEN'}(line 21, pos 87)"

Comment: T-SQL `CASE`  is an expression, not a control-of-flow statement. Try moving the expression to a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: `using delta` is in the query what you tried. Your Question is `In SQL Server, how can I insert a row?`. Are you using SQL server -T-SQL?

Comment: Hi @Aswin, i am using azure SQL.

Comment: Does Sql server support this `using delta`?

Comment: @Aswin, i am using azure SQL database not sql server.

Comment: Can we use `using delta` in azure SQL db?

Comment: @Aswin, yes I am working on azure SQL db.

Comment: Can u explain the requirements clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a WITH clause to gather the result set you want then insert after.

for example something like this

```
with tempTable(col1, col2) as 
( select 1, 2) 
insert into myTable(id1, id2)
(select col1, col2 from tempTable);
```